# Split order amount to accept offline and online payment based on vendor

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, multi-vendor, stripe

I have a multi-vendor marketplace where some sellers will accept offline payments only and some sellers will accept online payments. I want the users to be able to order products from these sellers in a single order.

How can I split the amount and payment method based on the seller's chosen payment method in a single order?

My payment gateway is Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

There are modules that use Stripe Connect to do this:

- https://store.webkul.com/magento2-multi-vendor-marketplace.html
- https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Stripe-Payment-Gateway.html
- https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/marketplace
- https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/marketplace/vendor-stripe-payment-addon
- https://www.mirakl.com/mirakl-b2c-marketplace-platform/
- https://magento.com/case-studies/ecommerce-store-albertsons
- https://magento.com/case-studies/b2b2c-mason-jars-marketplace

Answer (score 0):

To split the amount and payment method based on the seller's chosen payment method in a single order on a multi-vendor marketplace, you can follow these steps:

- Create a custom payment method for offline payments and enable it for the sellers who accept offline payments only.
- Use the Stripe payment gateway for sellers who accept online payments. There are modules to do this: https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html
- When a user places an order with products from multiple sellers, split the order into multiple orders based on the sellers' chosen payment method (offline or online).
- For orders with offline payments, assign the custom payment method created in step 1 and create an invoice for the seller.
- For orders with online payments, use the Stripe payment gateway and create an invoice for the seller.
  To implement this functionality, you may need to customize the Magento checkout and payment modules. You may also need to use a multi-vendor marketplace extension that supports this feature.